# Does Android.mk require AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, apk, android-10.0, android-make

I am trying to build my app as a part of the AOSP and realized that the `Android.mk` file does not take the path of the `AndroidManifest.xml` as input.

How can the `mm` command build the app with just the java files and the resources?

From where does the Android make get the information contained in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

**Note:**

Currently, my app is building with `mm` but has a smaller size (1MB vs 5MB) and does not show up on the device after adb install. Maybe this will fix it.

My `Android.mk` file for any reference

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES += \
    android-arch-lifecycle-extensions \
    android-support-v7-recyclerview \
    android-support-v7-appcompat \
    android-support-constraint-layout \

# Build all java files in the java subdirectory
#LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-subdir-java-files)
#Commented line just made a ~17kB apk file
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, app/src/main/java)
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR += $(LOCAL_PATH)/app/src/main/res

# Name of the APK to build
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := LocalPackage

LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current
#Otherwise build failing

# Tell it to build an APK
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml is needed for an android app (e.g. an installable .apk).  Android.mk is used to build an NDK binary (e.g. a C-language android shared library).  Apples and Oranges...

Comment: I am using `Android.mk` to build a system app. It is built along with the device binary.

Comment: I tried putting `Android.mk` in the same directory as `AndroidManifest.xml` and the manifest reflected inside the built apk. For more details follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68711139/apk-built-using-android-mk-mm-command-not-running-in-device-after-install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Android.mk` for an apk requires `AndroidManifest.xml`.
`Android.mk` for a NDK binary does not require `AndroidManifest.xml`.

The Android make gets the information contained in `AndroidManifest.xml` automatically if the `AndroidManifest.xml` is in the same path as the `Android.mk`.

I verified this by putting `Android.mk` in the same directory as `AndroidManifest.xml` and the manifest reflected inside the built apk.

For more details follow [APK built using Android.mk mm command not running in device after install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68711139/apk-built-using-android-mk-mm-command-not-running-in-device-after-install).